# Can't connect to WiFI after upgrade to 15.10, aka dreaded WPA2 Enterprise/PEAP nightmare

Tags: wireless, 15.10, wpa2, wpa-supplicant

Cannot connect to my school's WiFi network after an upgrade to Kubuntu 15.10

```
WPA2 Enterprise
PEAP 
no certificate
```

Network manager keeps asking for password (even though it has been supplied), but never connects.

I can connect via my Android phone

```
[connection]
id=Prof
uuid=2c64b06f-d391-47ed-987b-eae020c251b5
type=wifi
permissions=user:fx:;
secondaries=

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
seen-bssids=
ssid=Prof

[wifi-security]
group=
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
pairwise=
proto=

[802-1x]
altsubject-matches=
eap=peap;
identity=fpx
password-flags=1
phase2-altsubject-matches=
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
dns-search=
method=auto
```

So this is NOT the system-ca-cert=true problem- the line is absent

Any suggestions?

dmesg output :

```
[  319.869729] wlp2s0: authenticate with 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01
[  319.890789] wlp2s0: send auth to 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01 (try 1/3)
[  319.893335] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  319.897183] wlp2s0: associate with 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01 (try 1/3)
[  319.903786] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  319.903880] wlp2s0: associated
[  344.003693] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  344.015722] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  344.015727] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[  344.015728] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  344.015732] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  344.015735] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  344.015738] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  344.015741] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  344.015745] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  344.015747] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  344.015750] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  344.015753] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[  344.020244] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: IN
[  344.020248] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: JP
[  344.020249] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  344.020252] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  344.020255] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  344.020257] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  344.020258] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  353.950765] wlp2s0: authenticate with 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01
[  353.971680] wlp2s0: send auth to 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01 (try 1/3)
[  353.977292] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  353.978218] wlp2s0: associate with 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01 (try 1/3)
[  353.983815] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 9c:1c:12:2b:80:01 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  353.983907] wlp2s0: associated
```

Comment: Can you connect to other wifi networks?

Comment: Yes, no problem with any other network. But my school is the only network I use that uses WPA2  Enterprise.

Comment: Wow - this seems very similar - http://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap

Comment: yes, it's exactly the same situation.
the first solution, changing system-ca-cert=true does not apply, since my conf file does not have the line.
I also tried to downgrade wpasupplicant, but I get dependency problems and it breaks everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Currently the solution to this problem is to downgrade `wpasupplicant`:

[After upgrade to 15.10 Wifi to a corporate network (WPA2) is not working anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690032/after-upgrade-to-15-10-wifi-to-a-corporate-network-wpa2-is-not-working-anymore)

```
echo "deb http://london.mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ vivid main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivid.list
echo -e "Package: *\nPin: release o=Ubuntu,n=vivid\nPin-Priority: -1" | sudo tee cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/vivid
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant=2.1-0ubuntu7
sudo apt-mark hold wpasupplicant
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

I'm currently using the version 2.1.

```
wpa_supplicant -v
wpa_supplicant v2.1
Copyright (c) 2003-2014, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
```

Comment: I'm on the same version of wpa_supplicant (now using Ubuntu 16.04) and having an almost-identical issue. (Identical except our network uses a certificate.)