# Can't connect to WPA Enterprise wifi after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager, 16.04, wpa2

After upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04, I can't connect to my university's wifi (eduroam), which uses WPA2 Enterprise security. I'm certain the passwords and settings are all correct, and I had no trouble using the network with 15.04 and 15.10. As a matter of fact I even upgraded through that wifi, so I asked the IT department if they had changed anything just in case, which they haven't.

I have no trouble connecting to other Wifi networks, or detecting networks.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching around I've managed to fix it by downgrading wpasupplicant to version 2.1, deleting the connection and adding it back again, and restarting network-manager.

Got the solution from here, although I had no issue when I updated to 15.10:
[After upgrade to 15.10 Wifi to a corporate network (WPA2) is not working anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690032/after-upgrade-to-15-10-wifi-to-a-corporate-network-wpa2-is-not-working-anymore)