# WPA2 wifi refuses to connect after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager

I have two Ubuntu laptops next to each other at work at my university. I just upgraded one from 21.10 to 22.04.  After upgrade, the WPA2 for my university refuses my password / refuses to connect.  I can still connect to unsecured wifi networks.
My settings / authentication / certificates / etc are (a) correct and (b) identical to those of the other laptop, sitting next to it, which connects no problem.

I've updated, rebooted, quadruple-checked, etc.

Here's a similar-sounding very old problem: [Can't connect to WPA Enterprise wifi after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765167/cant-connect-to-wpa-enterprise-wifi-after-upgrading-from-15-10-to-16-04)  but that was more than half a decade ago.

Can anyone tell me the problem or how to troubleshoot? I've gone through the kind of advice here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-noconnection.html.en

Comment: I am also having issues with connecting to my work's "WPA & WPA2 Enterprise". Works perfectly fine on 20.04 - The regular "WPA & WPA2 Personal" guest wifi works fine. I double-checked all information and it all is correct on my end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are instructions for a workaround from launchpad. It solved my problem, but it sounds insecure / temporary. It also sounds like a proper patch/bug fix will be issued soon.

(UPDATE: A fix from Ubuntu has been completed and should filter out rapidly now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1958267 In the mean time, the procedure below may tide you over).

```
1. create openssl.cnf for wpa_supplicant
- sudo cp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/wpa_supplicant/
- modify /etc/wpa_supplicant/openssl.cnf by adding the lines below which are marked with a "+".
*** /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf Fri Apr 22 14:54:42 2022
--- /etc/wpa_supplicant/openssl.cnf Fri Apr 22 14:55:22 2022
***************
*** 52,57 ****
--- 52,64 ----

  [openssl_init]
  providers = provider_sect
+ ssl_conf = ssl_sect
+
+ [ssl_sect]
+ system_default = system_default_sect
+
+ [system_default_sect]
+ Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation

  # List of providers to load
2. modify /usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service
***************
*** 8,13 ****
--- 8,14 ----
  [Service]
  Type=dbus
  BusName=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1
+ Environment="OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/wpa_supplicant/openssl.cnf"
  ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
  ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
3. restart wpa_supplicant
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service
```

Comment: Wow! was struggling all day. This one worked prefectly.

Comment: Still waiting for authorization

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04.
I'm sure about the credential and config that I set, but I could not connect to my WPA2 Ent Wifi. My WPA2 Enterprise service reject me due to the credential that I entered but, this is right I used to use on my Ubuntu 20.04 without any issue.
I searched about this issue and I found that it was reported previously on beta versions of Ubuntu 22.04 and you can find more info on the following link:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1958267

and more specifically this comment describing the fix:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1963834/comments/7

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Updated today to (K)Ubuntu 22.04 and am not able to connect to any network with WPA2 Personal or WPA2 Enterprise Authentication.
But I was able to connect to a WPA2 Personal Network via netplan, so the issue seems to be in the Network Manager Plugin.

I added to /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml, so now I am able to use my home network:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "SSID OF NETWORK":
          password: "PASSWORD"
      dhcp4: true
```

EDIT: When I tried another account and was able to connect to the WiFi, I realised the problem had to be in my account configuration. But I didn't know where the configuration was stored. So I deleted all folders and files starting with 'plasma' and 'k' in my ~/.config folder and it worked again. I think it was one of the files/folders starting with k that did the trick, but I don't know which.

It also solved my Problem with Libreoffice not starting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just updated yesterday, had this same issue. My problem was that the system proxy setting was set to "Detect proxy configuration automatically" when there actually was no proxy. This also caused some apps like LibreOffice and Plasma to take much longer to load. All I did: in the GUI System Settings app > Network > Settings > Proxy > choose No Proxy. Then rebooted. After reboot, the wifi password dialog pops up, and connects like before.